# ggplot bar graph extra space

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to draw a graph using ggplot in R. Here are my codes:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
dfw <- read.table(header=T, text='
    Length  L1  L2
    200:399     27665   28483
    400:599     9232    11856
    600:799     3347    4072
    800:999     1923    2112
    1000:1199   1322    1511
    1200:1399   955 1118
    1400:1599   693 850
    1600:1799   496 640
    1800:1999   332 463
    2000:2199   219 306
    2200:2399   142 212
    2400:2599   73  134
    2600:2799   65  121
    2800:2999   39  87
    3000:3199   19  57
    3200:3399   20  31
    3400:3599   14  37
    3600:3799   4   22
    3800:3999   2   17
    4000:9599   8   53
')

 data.long <- melt(data = dfw, id.var = "Length", 
               measure.vars = c("L1", "L2"), variable.name = "Condition")

 ggplot(data=data.long, aes(x=Length, y=value, fill=Condition)) + 
         geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(width = 1), 
         colour="black", na.rm = TRUE, width = 0.5) + 
         scale_x_discrete(limits = data.long$Length) + 
         theme(axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold", colour="#990000", size=20),
         axis.text.x  = element_text(angle=90, vjust=2, size=16))
```

[image: ggplot2_my_plot]

My problem is no matter what I try, I cannot get rid of the extra space in the plotting area. Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: you've set limits here: `scale_x_discrete(limits = data.long$Length)`. Did you try removing that?

Comment: Yes, then it rearranged the x axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem in your code is that there are wrong order of levels in variable `Length`.
You can fix it with function `factor()` and argument `levels=dfw$Length` (as your original data frame has correct order).

```
data.long$Length<-factor(data.long$Length,levels=dfw$Length)
```

Now you don't need to use `scale_x_discrete()` to set limits.

```
 ggplot(data=data.long, aes(x=Length, y=value, fill=Condition)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(width = 1), colour="black", na.rm = TRUE, width = 0.5) + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold", colour="#990000", size=20),
        axis.text.x  = element_text(angle=90, vjust=2, size=16))
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove this `scale_x_discrete(limits = data.long$Length)` and try again hope this helps

EDIT : Remove the Y to by removing this if you have it `scale_y_discrete(limits = data.long$Length)`